# inner join (multi foreign key of a single table)

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join

i need your help

i have These tables in mssql server database :

```
match
---------------
matchid           int;
palyerA_fk        int;
playerB_fk        int;
playerA_scores    int;
playerB_scores    int;



players
---------------
id               int;
fullname         nvarchar;
```

**and i need this view :**

```
Resultsview
----------------
PlayerA_fullname  
PalyerA_scores 
PlayerB_fullname 
PlayerB_scores
```

please help me to create that view, thanks

.
.

this query is not returning any rows:

```
select a.fullname as playerAfullname , b.fullname as playerBfull name ,
 match.playerA_scores , match.playerB_scores 
from match 
inner join players as a on match.palyerA_fk = a.id 
inner join players as b on match.palyerB_fk = b.id
```

Comment: so, what's the problem ?

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Comment: You want us to do your sql statement or you have some code to put on your question ? (I hope...)

Comment: alias is not working on this , inner join works well to show first players fullname , but not working for second one

Comment: please suggest a query to me ; thank you

Comment: post the query that you have used

Comment: select a.fullname as playerAfullname , b.fullname as playerBfull name , match.playerA_scores , match.playerB_scores from match inner join players as a on match.palyerA_fk = a.id inner join players as b on match.palyerB_fk = b.id

Comment: Not as a comment, edit your question instead.

Comment: @jarlh thank you , this is my first asked question on stackoverflow . i'm new in this environment

Comment: What's wrong with your current query? Add some sample table data and the expected result (as formatted text, not images.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this

```
select a.fullname as playerAfullname , b.fullname as playerBfullname ,
m.playerA_scores , m.playerB_scores 
from match as m
inner join players as a on m.palyerA_fk = a.id 
inner join players as b on m.palyerB_fk = b.id
```